# When downloading multiple Google Spreadsheets via Drive API (exportLinks), why does my script throw a 404 for one of the files?

Tags: google-drive-api

Recently (5 days ago) I started seeing 404 errors from one of our python scripts as it attempts to download a Google SS through Drive API.  The script had been working well up until 5 days ago.

What's especially strange is that this script downloads several Google SS files and it's only this one file that throws a 404, the others download fine.

I've tried to recreate what the script does in the browser, and I'm stumped.

For example, in the case of a working/good GSS file:  I add a valid 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' to this URL

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/GOOD_GOOGLE_SS_KEY?download_url=file[%27exportLinks%27]

and I get a JSON response containing download links and other info about the file.  I tested one of the export links

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=GOOD_GOOGLE_SS_KEY&exportFormat=xlsx

and the file downloads just fine.

But things get weird when I try to go through the same process for the bad/404 file.  If I try to access the exportLinks url, I get a 404 error.  However, if I use the same "bad" file key in an export link, it downloads fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this?  File sharing settings?  File ownership settings?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up modifying the sharing settings on the file.  I was able to confirm that with link sharing set to "off", there is a 404 error.  When link sharing is set to "Anyone in *Domain* can view file with the link", there is no 404 error.